# change "New Item" word on new item creation in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, list-form

The requirement is to edit the new item view on the SharePoint Online list and edit the word appears on the top which is **New Item**[image: New Item]

Note: I have tried by editing content type name and opened new item form with SharePoint designer but that approach did not help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by creating a custom "New Form" via SharePoint Designer and there you can Change "New Item" to whatever you want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Melad - this solution does not work if the form is customized with PowerApps. Do you happen to know of a way to accomplish the same thing with the form being customized with PowerApps?